# How can I pull an array index value to a variable in powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables

I am wanting to pull the value of an array index element into another seperate value so that I can display the value to verify that was the correct choice from the user.

My first test was to just try and put the $Array[$ArrayIndex] into the verification read-host statement, and it returned the type of the object that I referenced in the array index, but when I just put the $Array[$ArrayIndex] into the powershell command line, it returns the info I want. I also tried to pull that into another variable like this: $arraychoice = $array[$arrayindex] and it pulls the same type statement: 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData

This is the code that I am currently using to initialize the array, enumerate it, and then ask the user if they need to change the time zone, allow them to choose a new TZ, and then verify their choice.

```
#get list of timezones.$tZs = Get-TimeZone -ListAvailable
#setup array for time zones
$tZNames = $tZs.id
$tzArray = @()
[string[]]$tZArray.AddRange($tZNames)
$tzAvail = $tzarray | foreach -Begin {$i=0} -Process {
    $i++
    "{0:D2}. {1}" -f $i,$_
    }
$tzlist = $tzavail

#Ask if they need to change the current time zone

while ($null -eq $tzchange)
{
        while( -not (($tzchange = (Read-host "Do you need to update the system to a different timezone?")) -match "y|n")){ "Y or N ?"}
            if ("y" -eq $tzchange) 
            {
                write-host "List of available Timezones:"
                $tzlist
                while ("y" -ne $tzverif)
                {
                    [int]$tzNew = Read-host "What timezone would you like to update the time zone to? (# from previous list)"
                    $tzActual = $tzList[$tzNew]
                    while( -not (($tzverif= (Read-host "You entered $tzActual is that correct?")) -match "y|n")){ "Y or N ?"}
                }
            }
}
```

I am wanting to just get the variable I pull the choice into to display the index element value:
in my tests I chose central standard time, so the choice of 15, should yield the value of:
15. Central Standard Time
In the line where $tzactual is

```
while( -not (($tzverif= (Read-host "You entered $tzActual is that correct?")) -match "y|n")){ "Y or N ?"}
```

Comment: have you actually run the code you posted? [*grin*] `Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'AddRange'.` ... that means you tried to use `AddRange()` on and **_array_** - which does not have that method. it DOES have an `.Add()` method ... but that fails. it really otta not be there.

Comment: your problem is also compounded by using `Format-Wide` ... that **_destroys_** your objects and  gives you the butchered bits wrapped in formatting code. there is no need for that, so leave it out.

Comment: you also have your `$i` index being incremented _before_ each array item is shown ... that gives you `1` when the actual index is `0`. that means your entire list is off by one.

Comment: I have run it, but I must have missed something when I was tinkering to try and get it to work, I'll clean it up.

Comment: your  problem is the one i mentioned about `Format-Wide`. DO NOT USE THE `FORMAT-*` cmdlets for anything other than _final screen output_ OR _final output to a plain text file_. NEVER use them anywhere that you need to use the _objects_ since the format cmdlets DESTROY your objects and send out the _butchered remnants wrapped in formatting code_.

Comment: I have made the edits that you had suggested, but I don't get the error you mention when using addrange, and if I don't, the entire list becomes a single element/index. I need it to be numbered so they can make a choice. Also I want to add a number first so that the first entry is 1 since it is a list for a user to pick from, and not all of them understand that 0 is an acceptable first choice.

Comment: Apparently it was the format-wide that was making it so that I got a value and not the actual entry. thank you Lee for letting me know that would affect the output like that. If you could, would you please list that as an actual answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: you are quite welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*] ///// i also posted a demo that i had prepped before i noticed your reply. hopefully it will be an interesting demo of alternate methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was your use of `Format-Wide`. that cmdlet - and all the `Format-*` cmdlets - chop up your objects, wrap them in formatting code, and then send those butchered bits out. [*grin*] they should ONLY be used for *final output to screen* OR *final output to a plain text file*.

NEVER use them for anything where you need to use the objects later ... you won't *have* those objects any more.

---

here is an alternate way to get the user to choose an item from a list of the objects in a collection ...

```
$TimeZoneList = (Get-TimeZone -ListAvailable).DisplayName
$CurrentTimeZone = (Get-TimeZone).DisplayName

'The current time zone is {0}.' -f $CurrentTimeZone
$Choice = Read-Host 'Do you want to change that? [n/y]'
if ($Choice -eq 'y')
    {
    $Choice = $Null
    while ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Choice))
        {
        $TimeZoneList.ForEach({
            '{0, 4} - {1}' -f $TimeZoneList.IndexOf($_), $_
            })
        ''
        $Choice = Read-Host 'Please select a TimeZone by number '
        if ([int]$Choice -notin 0..$TimeZoneList.GetUpperBound(0))
            {
            [System.Console]::Beep(1000, 300)
            Write-Warning ''
            Write-Warning ('    Your coice [ {0} ] is not valid.' -f $Choice)
            Write-Warning '    Please try again ...'
            Write-Warning ''

            $Choice = $Null
            pause
            }
            else
            {
            $ChosenTimeZone = $TimeZoneList[[int]$Choice]
            'You chose {0} - {1}.' -f $Choice, $ChosenTimeZone
            $Choice = Read-Host 'Is that the TimeZone you want to use? [n/y]'
            if ($Choice -eq 'n')
                {
                $Choice = $ChosenTimeZone = $Null
                }
            }
        } # end >>> while ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Choice))
    } # end >>> if ($Choice -eq 'y')

''
'Current TimeZone = {0}' -f $CurrentTimeZone
'Chosen replacement TimeZone = {0}' -f $ChosenTimeZone
''
```

invalid choice output ...

```
Please select a TimeZone by number : 1234
WARNING: 
WARNING:     Your coice [ 1234 ] is not valid.
WARNING:     Please try again ...
WARNING: 
Press Enter to continue...:
```

valid choice output ...

```
Please select a TimeZone by number : 12
You chose 12 - (UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada).
Is that the TimeZone you want to use? [n/y]: y

Current TimeZone = (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
Chosen replacement TimeZone = (UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)
```